# Save touches on libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, touch

Is it possible to save first touch, release and then read second or new touches while rendering libgdx? I've only found this Gdx.input.isTouched (int) while int is the index for how many fingers at the same time, but I need releasethe first and then do more touches.

If this question is answered before, where?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to safe the coordinates of the touch?

`Gdx.justTouched` will only run a single time until released. Or you can implement `GestureListener` and use it's `tap(int x, int y, int button)` method.

So just store `Gdx.input.getX` and `Gdx.input.getY` when a touch is detected and you have these saved until you save the next touch over it again.

Comment: I'm using isTouched but only works for android, I assumed isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT) is for left button on windows, haven't tested. I also did the getX and getY with positions and other things I've found around the community, but get lost with it. I need at least two touches,  like drawing when touched and leaving there and then draw again in another touch of screen. I'll try with just touched

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own InputProcessor and override your touchDown and touchUp events by this:

declare your touches hashmap:

```
 private Map<Integer,TouchInfo> touches = new HashMap<Integer,TouchInfo>();
```

the touchDown event:

```
          @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            if(touches.get(pointer) == null){
                touches.put(pointer, new TouchInfo());
            }
                touches.get(pointer).touchX = screenX;
                touches.get(pointer).touchY = screenY;
                touches.get(pointer).touched = true;
            return true;
        }
```

and the touchUp event:

```
@Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            touches.get(pointer).touchX = 0;
            touches.get(pointer).touchY = 0;
            touches.get(pointer).touched = false;
        return true;
    }
```

The TouchInfo class:

```
class TouchInfo {
        public float touchX = 0;
        public float touchY = 0;
        public boolean touched = false;
    }
```

you can handle as many touchs as your device supports or if you want you can limit the inputs as you wish.